# Pandas data frame creation using static data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I have a data set like this : {'IT',[1,20,35,44,51,....,1000]}
I want to convert this into python/pandas data frame. I want to see output in the below format. How to achieve this output.

```
Dept  Count
IT      1
IT      20
IT      35
IT      44
IT      51
..      .
..      .
..      .
IT      1000
```

Below way i can write, but this is not efficient way for huge data.

```
data = [['IT',1],['IT',2],['IT',3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Dept','Count'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension for tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
d = {'IT':[1,20,35,44,51], 'NEW':[1000]}

data = [(k, x) for k, v in d.items() for x in v]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Dept','Count'])
print(df)

  Dept  Count
0   IT      1
1   IT     20
2   IT     35
3   IT     44
4   IT     51
5  NEW   1000
```

Answer (score 4):

No need for a list comprehension since `pandas` will automatically fill IT in for every row.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'IT':[1,20,35,44,51,1000]}
df = pd.DataFrame({'dept': 'IT', 'count': d['IT']})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `melt`

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'IT': [10]*100000} 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = pd.melt(df, var_name='Dept', value_name='Count')
```